# Windows 2008 R2 server AWS Disabling Folder is ready for archiving

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Windows 2008 server R2 on AWS.
I've spent a while searching for a way to set a registry key or find a command line argument that will let me enable or disable a folders Advanced Attributes such as...."Folder is ready for archiving" ....etc.  I mainly need to know how to do this for the setting "Folder is ready for archiving".  I have many systems that I need to set this on.
For those who are unfamiliar with what I'm talking about.If you right click a folder and click the "Advanced" tab..all these settings are listed in check boxes.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are looking for the [attrib](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/attrib.mspx?mfr=true) command

```
attrib +a c:\foldername /s
```